# why is my JS is working only when I debug?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a **container** with two divs, **content1** with an **open** button and **content2**.

There are two tabs, **content1Tab** and **content2Tab**, which when clicked should show content1 and 2 respectively using z-index.

the **open** button in **content1** loads **container** with **containerOther** from **page.php**.
All this seems to work only
 only when I step through the code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("#content1Tab, #content2Tab").click(function(event) {          
        var myString = $(this).attr('id');
        var parts = myString.split("Tab");
        var thePart = parts[0];
        $("#container").load("../index.php #container> *", function() {                
            $('#btnOpen').click(function(){ 
                $("#container").load("../page.php #containerOther> *");
            });
        });
        $("#content1Tab, #content2Tab").css('z-index', 7);
        $(this).css('z-index', 9);
        $("#content1, #content2").css('z-index', 7);
        $("#"+thePart).css('z-index',9);
    });
});
```

When I just run the index page the code seems to stop at line 6

```
 $("#container").load("../index.php #container> *"
```

As in, **container** shows **content1** no matter which tab I click on and the **open** button doesn't work.

Comment: Async "problem" here, searching dupe questions...

Comment: A more specific explanation of what is or isn't happening would be helpful. Also are those tabs being replaced with the content from `load()`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an error here `"../index.php #container> *"`. The load function will try to load URL "index.php%20%23container%3E%20*" instead of index.php.

I think it should be just "../index.php".

Comment: but I'm trying to load the *contents* of **container** from the index.php file.

Comment: OK, this makes sense then.